# non_lazy_pointer problem

Tags: xcode, linker

I am getting following error while building . I tried searching on web as well for this error,but could not find a solution, suited for my problem. Searching on the web, I found two solutions :

1. Either use the compiler g++.
2. Add library stdc++ on the command, so that libstdc++ can be linked with.
   Actually both results are almost same, since g++ itself adds libstdc++ to the command before linking.

I tried this solution, but it didn’t solve the problem. Thedifference between my problem and problem described on web is that in my case,undefined symbol is **_gxx_personality_v0$non_lazy_ptr,while all other problems described on web, describes missing**_gxx_personality_v0. I tried searching for ___gxx_personality_v0$non_lazy_ptr in the libstdc++ and other libs as well using “nm”, but could not find this symbol.
If anybody has any clue about tthis problem, please let me know.

/usr/bin/cc  -prebind -o PROD "other .o's" "other libs"   -lgcc_eh

Undefined symbols:
  "___gxx_personality_v0$non_lazy_ptr",referenced from:

…
…
….
…
Error Icould found on web :
Undefinedsymbols:
"___gxx_personality_v0", referencedfrom:      è problems other encountered was that undefined symbol was__gxx_personality_v0.
___gxx_personality_v0$non_lazy_ptrin cciIlcV9.o  è In my case (see in my message), this is the undefined symbol. "std::basic_ostream >& std::endl >(std::basic_ostream >&)", referenced from:
__ZSt4endlIcSt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES6_$non_lazy_ptrin cciIlcV9.o
"std::ios_base::Init::~Init()",referenced from:
…
…
…
Thanks& Regards,

Answer (score 0):

it's a pain to maintain the std c++ libs when targeting several platforms/sdks in Xcode.

the easier way is to use Xcode's link against standard libraries option, and to ensure your target compiles at least one c++ file.